# Where are the SAS formats defined?

Tags: sas

When I start up my SAS session and define a library to a folder:

```
LIBNAME testlib "C:\DATA\&YRMTH\TEST\";
```

When I navigate to `testlib`, I already see a bunch of formats defined and ready to use. I am not sure where they are defined and I cannot find them.  I need to edit one of these formats, how do I locate the source? YRMTH is a macro variable that contains YYYYMM, corresponding to today's date.

Comment: Do you mean in Windows Explorer if you go to the folder C:\Data\YYYYMM\Test you see a format catalog there, named something like formats.sas7bcat ?  Such a format was likely built with code, so you could look for that code.  As Richard said, if you can't find the code, you can use PROC FORMAT CNTLOUT to write the format to a dataset, then you can edit that dataset and user PROC FORMAT CNTLIN to update the format.  Perhaps edit your question to show the format you have, and the format you would like to generate.

Answer (score 1):

`Proc FORMAT` source code is not stored with the resultant created format catalog entry.

A format catalog in one of your own libraries can be added to the format search path using the option.  From [Usage Note 23007: How can I permanently store and use formats that I have created?](http://support.sas.com/kb/23/007.html)

> `OPTIONS FMTSEARCH=(catalog-specification-1... catalog-specification-n);`

You may be in a situation where you never find the original source code that created the format!  However, all is not lost.  The *control data* of a custom format can *extracted* using `PROC FORMAT CNTLOUT=`.  A custom format can be *edited* by manipulating the extracted control data and running it back into with `PROC FORMAT CNTLIN=` to recreate (overwriting) the original custom format.  Remember, that could be a non-reversible process if you do not take care to backup or archive your catalog, catalog entry or extracted control data.

Not sure how your macro variable gets involved with a discussion of formats.  Update the question if there is more information to share.